# PHP MySQL search for name like %John D% in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to find a list of people's names that match a search. My php:

```
require "accessControl.php";
require "sqlLink.php";

$string = "%dan%";

// create a prepared statement
if ($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT full_name FROM (SELECT *, CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) AS full_name FROM users) tmp WHERE full_name LIKE ?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $string);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($result);

    $stmt->fetch();

    $stmt->close();
}

echo $result;
```

This just gives a 500 error, but when I replace the query with `"SELECT lastname FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE ?"`, it works fine. I spent over an hour searching for a solution, but I'm pretty confused.

Comment: I can't believe I did that! Anyway thank you, that should have occurred to me right off the bat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace condition in your `if` with this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT full_name FROM (SELECT *, CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) AS full_name FROM users) tmp WHERE full_name LIKE ?")
```

Here, you just need to replace `" "` with `' '` in your `CONCAT()` function because that would break your entire string which also starts and ends with `"`.

Comment: Why should that solve the problem? What is wrong with this `if`?

Comment: Well, if you check carefully that would certainly result in 500 error.

Comment: It's worth noting that **you should have mentioned** that the problem is that the double quotes within the concat terminate the PHP string and therefore produce a syntax error. Just dumping code as a solution may help OP but will not help anyone else.

Comment: @apokryfos If you can see I've clearly mentioned that at the end of the answer.

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting downvotes even though I've pointed out the exact issue. I better delete it. -_-

Comment: I downvoted because of the issue I mentioned but then you edited to correct it so I retracted the downvote.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for your courtesy!

Answer (score 2):

First don't use " "  inside duoble quoted string  .. becuase break the string continuity.
second you could use concat for buil string with wilchar

```
$string = "dan";
$link->prepare("SELECT full_name FROM (
                SELECT *, CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) AS full_name FROM users
              ) tmp WHERE full_name LIKE concat( '%', ?, '%'))");
```